# background slideshow refuses keyboard control

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I'm working on a clickable slideshow that uses `background-image:url()` to display the images.

For some reason, the implemented keyboard arrow control doesn't work and blocks everything.

Any idea how to fix it? [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kreemers/bvg3tpfc/) and code snippet below.

```js
$(".FS").each(function () {
    var $bg = $(this).find("> div"),
    n = $bg.length,
    c = 0;

    $bg.hide().on("click", function () {
        $bg.fadeOut().eq(++c % n).fadeIn();
    }).eq(c).show();
});

//keys
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        $('.FS').click();
    }
```

```css
.FS {
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.FS div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: none 50% / cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FS">
<div style="background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/83ibckD.jpg)"> </div>
<div style="background-image:url(http://www.elevation9640.com/wp- content/uploads/2010/03/baby-goats.jpg)"></div>
<div style="background-image:url(http://waywardspark.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/DSC_0023.jpg)"></div>
```

Comment: You have not closed the `keypress` method. Put `});` at the end of it. Also, open your developer console and learn to debug code using all the tools available to you.

Comment: Also, click is called on the `.fs` div, while the click event is attached to its children. You could do something like `$('.FS > div').first().click();`, or better yet attach the click to the .fs element directly ( `$(this)` ), but imho it's better to expose a function that's used both for the click and keypress events.

Comment: my bad, was a bit to quick copying code. closing the keypress and changing the click however do not solve the problem.

Comment: When I attach the click event to $(this) as in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bvg3tpfc/67/ , the left arrow works when testing in FireFox. (after the first click, so that the fiddle has the proper focus I assume)

Comment: You're right, it works in firefox. Sadly no response in safari or chrome. Anyway workaround for this?

Comment: You could try keydown instead of keypress, some browsers don't expose keypress for special keys: http://jsfiddle.net/bvg3tpfc/68/